# How to coordinate send and receive with UDF DatagramSockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp

I have an integration test that needs to coordinate two [DatagramSockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html), each running in their own thread.  One socket waits to read data with a blocking call to receive().  The other socket needs to call send(), but this must happen after receive() has blocked, otherwise the data will be lost.

The code is a little like this:

**Receiver**

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
new DatagramSocket(7654).receive(new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length));
```

**Sender**

```
new DatagramSocket(7654).send(
    new DatagramPacket("hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), 5));
```

I'm loath to put a Thread.sleep() before the send() call, although this would probably be sufficient to allow the receiver to block.  Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: UDP doesn't have a handshake method to coordinate this type of work. A rudimentary solution would be to blast the receiver with packets waiting for a "ready" signal then once a confirmation is received by the sender the actual data goes through. I didn't post this as an answer because I'm certain there's a better method which someone can point you to. Maybe [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi) would be helpful?

Comment: I'd thought of that, too.  I was hoping that there might be a way to coordinate things with Java concurrency tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait on a semaphore just before the send().  Signal a unit just before the receive() call.  Given network delays, I would be amazed if a UDP reply arrived back before the receive() call was made and the rx socket set up.  You could make sure by raising the priority of the receive thread, (or lowering the priority of the send thread).

You could wait on another semaphore after the send() and signal it after the receive(), so ensuring that the send thread does not attempt to send again until the rx is done.  Not sure how you would detect comms failures, IIRC, Java semaphore waits do not have a timeout :((

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: This is probably good enough, though it doesn't eliminate the race condition entirely.  I'm not sure what you mean by a 'UDP reply'.  At the moment, the receiver doesn't send a response back to the sender.  [Java semaphores](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) are interruptible and you can specify timeouts.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood - it the receiver does not send a reply what 'data will be lost'?  I assumed that the peer sent a UDP reply that would be discarded by the stack if the receiving thread was not waiting for it.

Comment: The data sent from the sender to the receiver will be lost if the receive() has not yet been called.

Comment: I understand you're creating a stub for communication modules in your tests but are the production devices on a single machine sharing memory? If not then semaphores will only work for your test an possibly mask issues with concurrency that would exist in production. Again, disregard if the sender/receiver are on a single machine sharing memory but I don't see why UDP would be necessary if you are (just use message passing through shared memory with semaphores)

Comment: OK, I've just twigged that the two sockets are on the same box, not communicating over the network with another app instance that is sending a reply.  *Now* I understand!

Comment: @TheCapn Perhaps I should provide more background :)  The receiver is the test stub, the sender is the production code.  In a real environment, I can assume that the UDP receiver, which is a different process running on a different machine, will always be listening so there's no need for coordination.